# Magento 2 customer CAPTCHA Login Not Showing Up

Tags: customer, login, magento2.2.2, captcha, recaptcha

I have added all possible captcha forms in `Stores->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->CAPTCHA` see screen shoot bellow:
[image]

Clear cache,flush yet the login page doesn't show it.

[image]

Anyone any idea is this a bug?

Comment: please check `enable` value at store level. are you using a custom theme ?

Comment: @Pawan I can tell you that I am using Luma as this is test environment and yes it's enable  Screen shoots are attached, to better answer your question! I've checked website level is using default as store view level isn't available to change this values. all other forms are showing CAPTCHA

Answer (score 0):

If your theme is extending Magento_Blank theme, then you don't need to copy the entire contents of the customer_account_login.xml file to your theme to make changes to it --> this will "bug out" the CAPTCHA form.

The proper way to make changes is to use  and  to add, remove or move the elements as you want.

You can read instructions here on how to do that: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

If you are facing the same issue, you can quickly test it by renaming/removing your theme's `customer_account_login.xml` and clearing cache.

Then you can make the customizations the proper way based on the official documentation.

Comment: Does Luma Theme counts? No custom theme is applied !

Comment: I think yes it counts

Comment: @ Rahul Singh Thanks. So it's a bug on Luma Theme!